# React Hook (useState, setState) is both true and false

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I have a React state variable `const [pickingHotspot, setPickingHotspot] = useState(false);`. I then have this button `<button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-danger" onClick={() => setPickingHotspot(true)}>` which just sets the state to true onClick. I have another handler

```
tmp.on('mousedown', (event) => {
    if (pickingHotspot){
        console.log(tmp.mouseEventToCoords(event));
    } else {
        console.log(pickingHotspot);
    }
});
```

where `tmp` is a Pannellum 360 Image Viewer (its a third party library, but I don't think it matters what it is), and this is set in my `useState(...,[])` which runs once on load. Lastly, I have an onClick div that just prints the value of `pickingHotspot` for debugging purposed. Here's the weird part:

When I load the page and click the debug div, the value is false. Cool, that works. Then I click the button (which should set it to true!) and then click the debug div again. The value is true! But when I click the Pannellum viewer, the value is false? I'm not sure how the value could possibly be both true ***and*** false, depending on where I click. Are there different versions/instances of these variables? I've tried linking everything to individual function handlers that are outside of the html components and outside of the useEffect in case there's some weird scope stuff happening, but nothing has worked so far.

I tried to show all of the code needed, but here's the full thing (I took most of the unrelated stuff out to simplify it, its a lot of code to look through.):

```
function TourCreator(props){

    
    const [scenes, setScenes] = useState({});
    const [media, setMedia] = useState({});
    const [viewer, setViewer] = useState(null);

    // Editor states
    const [pickingHotspot, setPickingHotspot] = useState(false);


    

    function handle(event){
        if (pickingHotspot){
            console.log(viewer.mouseEventToCoords(event));
        } else {
            console.log(pickingHotspot);
        }
    }


    // Called once on load
    useEffect(() => {

        if (Object.keys(media).length == 0){

            // Sends the request to the backend for "data"
            sendGetRequest(window.$PROJECT, true, {
                id: params["project_id"],
            }).then((data) => {

                data.images = reshapeArray(data.images, 3);
                console.log(data)

                setMedia(data);
                let tmp = window.pannellum.viewer('panorama', tour)
                setViewer(tmp);

                // Print Pitch/Yaw on click
                tmp.on('mousedown', (event) => handle(event));
                
            });
        }  
        
    }, [])

    
    return (
        <div className="p-3">

            
            {/* MAIN CONTENT */}
            <div className='tour-creator-root mx-auto p-3 row rounded'>

                {/* MAIN BOX */}
                <div className='main-box col-9 px-0 rounded'>

                    {/* Pannellum viewer */}
                    <div id='panorama' className="w-100 rounded-top">
                        <button type="button" className="save-button btn btn-outline-danger">
                            Save
                        </button>

                    </div>


                    {/* Toolbar */}
                    <div className="toolbar w-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center rounded-bottom p-3"
                    onClick={
                        () => {
                            console.log(pickingHotspot)
                        }
                    }>

                        <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around">

                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-danger" onClick={
                                () => setPickingHotspot(true)
                            }>
                                Add Hotspot
                            </button>

                        </div>

                    </div>


                </div>

                
            </div>

        </div>
    )

}


export default TourCreator;
```

Comment: This might be happening because your dependency array(useEffect) is missing the pickingHotspot value. The event handler is added once, and the value of pickingHotspot at that time is referred again. So it is always false. Try passing pickingHotspot in your dependency array for useEffect.

Comment: Try Tushar's answer and change your onClick function by this: onClick={() => setPickingHotspot(!pickingHotspot)}

Comment: @TusharShahi Thanks! Your answer does in fact work. I still don't fully understand why React interprets the value as being the same, but I'll just work with it. The only other thing that happens now is that because `useEffect` gets called on each change to `pickingHotspot`, another event handler gets added each time it changes. Is there any way to override this or remove previous event handlers?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing pickingHotspot in your dependency array for useEffect.

Your event handler is attached to your element in the useEffect on componentDidMount because of the empty dependency array. This will only happen once and that old function will be used. That old function will [close](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) over the value of the previous state. You can attach your event handler again on every relevant state change by passing pickHotSpot in your [dependency array](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect).

It is also a recommended approach to keep all your relevant code inside the hook. You could have put your listener function inside your hook, and would have seen a missing dependency warning from one of your lint tools.

Also, if there is no specific reason for you to add event hanlder like this from javascript, then add inline usin JSX, like @MB__ suggested. That will be executed on every render so it should be correct. At any time only one eventhandler for the particular event will be attached.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Just got it to work. I'd never heard of the stale stuff before, so that was super helpful.

Comment: Great. Consider up-voting/accepting if this helped you.